# Why are the cookies not being set when doing a Redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Or maybe i am doing it wrong, why are the cookies not being set when doing a Redirect?

```
static void doLogin()
{
    var req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    ...
    user_cookie.set(userId, loginId);
    ...
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(req["returnLocation"]);
}

static public void set(long userId, long loginId)
{
    var cookies = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies;
    var u = new HttpCookie("userId", userId.ToString());
    u.HttpOnly = true;
    var l = new HttpCookie("loginId", loginId.ToString());
    l.HttpOnly = true;
    cookies.Add(u);
    cookies.Add(l);
}
```

Comment: Where are you redirecting to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding cookies to the **Request**.Cookies collection, you'll want to add them to the **Response**.Cookies collection instead.

Also note that Response.Redirect will abort the current thread which I've seen cause problems on occasion. Response.Redirect( url, false ) will redirect without aborting.