# Why is the cookie I set in the server not showing in the client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am not able to read a cookie on the client that I set on the server.

I am using C# / MVC and am handling the cookie logic outside of the controller.

I pass in the Response, and can see it is set after I call this method from the controller, but once the response gets sent to the client, this cookie is not present.

In the controller, I am calling the SetCookie method like this:

```
CookieHelper.SetCookie(Response);
```

I have also tried to pass in `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response` to no avail.

The method I am calling is:

```
public class CookieHelper {

    public static void SetCookie(HttpResponseBase Response)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("jayscookie");
        cookie.Value = "a much longer string than this";
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }

}
```

I have tried `HttpResponseWrapper` as well.
I have also tried `System.Net.Cookie` instead of `HttpCookie`

My IIS Setting for Session State is represented by this line in the Web.Config:

`<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" cookieless="false"/>`

I have tried without `cookieless="false"`

The Cookie Settings section of this application in IIS are:

Mode: `UseCookies`
Name: `ASP.NET_SessionId`
Time-out: `20` (minutes)

I have visited the following and tried solutions:

[Why is my cookie not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478527/why-is-my-cookie-not-set)

[Cookies not getting set in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399717/cookies-not-getting-set-in-c-sharp)

[Why are the cookies not being set when doing a Redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036889/why-are-the-cookies-not-being-set-when-doing-a-redirect)

[Cookie not setting in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621119/cookie-not-setting-in-asp-net-mvc)

[How to set cookie value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556061/how-to-set-cookie-value)

[HttpWebRequest/Reponse return cookies sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154029/httpwebrequest-reponse-return-cookies-sent)

As well as several microsoft documentation pages, such as:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

Is there anything I am missing, or any basic concept I am obviously not taking into account?  Setting cookies on the client works fine, just not setting them on the server.

Comment: Cookies that are sent to the browser in the Response right? But when they are sent back to you, on the next request, they're found in the Request.

Comment: Are you doing a redirect? This is a usual case when a cookie "disappears".

Comment: @Tasos K., I am not doing a redirect.

Comment: @JesseMoreland, They are not being sent back, and therefore are not present in the Request. (Which is how I found out all this was happening.)

Comment: Is there a `StateServer` configured at `127.0.0.1:42424` and is the ASP.NET state `service` running? Have you tried `InProc` (default) first to debug if it's code level vs config?

Comment: @EdSF , It is configured, and the service is running.  I can save values to the Session variable, but just not cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cookie.Value` string was a different value in my application.  The value in the application was far too big, and exceeded the limit for cookie size.  I will have to figure out a different approach, but that was the issue.

The size limit for cookies is around 4KB, for any who may find this information useful.

Answer (score -1):

Server side can t access client side directly and vice versa. Sorry for poor explain but i'm in train

Comment: I am aware of that.  I am trying to check client side via a browser.  Thank you though